# pandas groupby and map list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two dataframes,
where 1st dataframe contains list of cells and person names.
2nd dataframe contains the actual values to be mapped to.

df1:

```
Name           celllist
Bob            ['a', 'v']
April          ['b', 'c']
Amy            ['v']
Linda          ['g', 'r']
```

df2:

```
Name    cell    value
Bob      a       4
Bob      g       6
Bob      v       8
Arpil    a       6
Arpil    g       8
Arpil    b       9
Arpil    c       1
Amy      v       2
Amy      b       2
```

This is what I would like to have, I want to extract values from df2 for the cellist elements and add them back to the df1.

excpected Result:
df1:

```
Name           Group          Group_Name
Bob            ['a', 'v']         [4, 8]       
April          ['b', 'c']         [9, 1]
Amy            ['v']              [2]
Linda          ['g', 'r']         [None, None]
```

Can someone help me to get this or suggest any better solution?

Comment: what are you trying to map. Are you trying to concat df1 and the groupby results from df2? What is your expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question. posted the expected result. I am not doing any concatenation.  just grouped by Name in df2. after this, I am nt able to proceed.

Comment: df2.groupby() gives you the result you have posted. What do you want to do with this? And what is the expected output once you process df1 and df2. Unable to understand what you want to do next. What do you want to do with map?

Comment: after doing the grouby in df2, I have list of values in 'cell' and 'value' columns. I want these values of 'value' column in df1 for corresponding 'Group' column elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you need to group only those values in the list or NaN, so do:

```
# create DataFrame to check which values of cell are in Group
res = df2.merge(df1, on='Name', how='right').explode('Group')

# create mask 
mask = res['Group'].eq(res['cell']) | res['cell'].isna()

# filter, group by, agg and rename
output = res[mask].groupby('Name', sort=False).agg({'Group': list, 'value': list}).rename(
    columns={'value': 'Group Name'})
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
        Group  Group Name
Name                     
Bob    [a, v]  [4.0, 8.0]
April  [b, c]  [9.0, 1.0]
Amy       [v]       [2.0]
Linda  [g, r]  [nan, nan]
```

**UPDATE**

For keeping the original list order, you could add an additional step:

```
# create DataFrame to check which values of cell are in Group
res = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left').explode('Group', ignore_index=True)

# reorder DataFrame to keep original list order
res['ord'] = np.arange(len(res))
res['ord'] = res.groupby(['Name', 'Group'])['ord'].transform('first')
res = res.sort_values(by='ord').drop('ord', 1)

# create mask
mask = res['Group'].eq(res['cell']) | res['cell'].isna()

# filter, group by, agg and rename
output = res[mask].groupby('Name', sort=False).agg({'Group': list, 'value': list}).rename(
    columns={'value': 'Group Name'})
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For the large datasets, is merging going to take time?

Comment: You could create Indexes to speed up the merge, if needed

Comment: I think a few steps here are unnecessary and are just computational overheads. I address this in my answer.

Comment: Hi Dani. the output can change the order of the group and doesn't maintain the original order if the order in df2 is chnaged. How can I get the values in the same order of input list?

Comment: @anjali You could try `# create DataFrame to check which values of cell are in Group
res = df1.merge(df2, on='Name', how='left').explode('Group')` as a first step and let me know

Comment: Sorry. I did a mistake. It is not changing the order as per the given dataframes. But suppose if I give the order in the df1, instead of ['b','c'] as ['c','b'], then it is chnaging the order.

Comment: as a first step, it converts all the list elemnts to rows in df1 and merges with df2. Hence the value expands for all the possible combinations.

Comment: perfect. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe a few steps in Dani's method above can be truly avoided.
The mask creation is unnecessary.
If the input dataframe is leveled before merging this solves the problem better and faster. Any keys that don't need matching are ignored in the larger dataframe, and the intermediate results are kept as lean as possible.

```
# Assuming df as first dataframe and df2 as larger 2nd dataframe
df.explode('celllist').merge(
    df2, how='left',
    left_on=['Name', 'celllist'],
    right_on=['Name', 'cell']
).drop(columns=['cell']).groupby('Name', sort=False).agg(
    {'celllist': list, 'value': list}).rename(
    columns={'celllist': 'Group', 'value': 'Group Name'})
```

This yields the output just as desired by the OP.

**Output:**

```
        Group   Group Name
Name        
Bob     [a, v]  [4.0, 8.0]
April   [b, c]  [9.0, 1.0]
Amy     [v]     [2.0]
Linda   [g, r]  [nan, nan]
```

Comment: It's cool. You should accept a solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: Both of the solutions work for me. But I can also have multiple columns on the df1,  other than name and celllist  with a fixed string that should not change anytime, like df1['r']='r'. The output for both cases, doesn't provide the extra columns (r) on df1 if it do exist originally. If I try to merge the outputdf with original df1, it is giving error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: The error could be due to merging on columns including `Group` which is a list.
For merging with the original table, only the `Name` column should suffice since it is already aggregated at `Name` level and is guaranteed to have unique `Name` for all rows. For that reason, `Name` is also an index in the aggregated dataframe if you notice.